# Show $[\sigma(f), \mathcal{E}]$-measurability of a function and descirbe the $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $[E,\mathcal{E}]$ be a measurable space and let
> $f:\Omega\rightarrow E$. Show that $f$ is
> $[\sigma(f),\mathcal{E}]$-measurable. In particular, when
> $E=\mathbb{R}, f$ is a random variable on $[\Omega,\sigma(f)]$.
> Describe the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $f$ taking the two values
> $0$ and $1$.

Let's begin by looking at the definition of measurability of functions.

**Definition:** *Let* $(X,\mathcal{A})$ *and* $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ *be measurable spaces. A function* $f:X\rightarrow Y$ *is masurable if* $f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{A}$ *for every* $B\in\mathcal{B}$.

So I know now what measurable function is, but what is a $[\sigma(f),\mathcal{E]}$-measurable function? I have previously shown that the inverse images of $\sigma{f}=\{f^{-1}(B):B\in\mathcal{E}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra but I don't see how to proceed here.

Comment: Is a tautology. All function $f:X\to E$ is $[\sigma (f),\mathcal E]-$measurable. to say that $g:F\to E$ is $[\mathcal F,\mathcal E]$ measurable means that $f^{-1}(E)\in \mathcal F$ for all $E\in \mathcal E$.

Comment: So essentially, If I prove that $f{-1}(E)\in\mathcal{F}$ then I have proven that $f$ is $[\sigma(f), \mathcal{E}]$-measurable? Can you also explain the conclusion made when $E=\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: No, if you prove that $f^{-1}(E)\in \sigma (f)$ for all $E\in \mathcal E$, then $f$ is $\sigma (f)-\mathcal E$ measurable. But this is true by definition of $\sigma (f)$, so the question has no sense (or is a tautology...)